# Siren "more like this" query

Tags: search, solr, morelikethis, siren

i am using the newest Siren distribution for Solr to index my data and search it. (http://siren.solutions/siren/downloads/)

Is there a simple way to search similar documents in my indexed data. Something similar to the  MoreLikeThis query of Solr (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis).

My goal is to find documents that have a similar json structure that the one i am interested in.

best,
Bernd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember SIREn stores the RDF representation of each resource within a dedicated field of the Solr document. I don't think the default MLT component that comes with Solr works for your scenario.
I mean, enabling that component will produce some kind of result but I don't believe that it will follow your json "similarity" requirement.

On top of that I suggest you to post your request on SIREn mailing list [1]: I'm sure the dev team will address you on the right path.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/siren-user

Comment: ok Thx, yeah i already tried the mailing list but the without success